# Extract specific section

Tags: text-processing

I have multiple sections, each consisting of multiple lines.
e.g:

```
#--- Section 1 ---
Start  
Lookup.mdc|123|xyz|  
String  
End
#--- Section 2 ---
Start  
Lookup.mdc|123|xyz|  
Integer  
End
```

My requirement is: I need to extract only that section which contains **Integer**(Datatype search) in it.

Expected Output:

```
Start  
Lookup.mdc|123|xyz|  
Integer
End
```

Comment: The question has been edited, originally the section headers showed as starting with `---`, but now show as starting `#---`. Which is correct? If the latter then I should update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="^--- Section [0-9]+"} /Integer/ {print}'
```

and either pipe the input into it, or add the filename onto the end.

You don't need the `{print}`, as that is the default action, but I put it in to make it clearer.

The `BEGIN` is executed before the input is processed, and sets the magic variable `RS` (Record Separator) to match the line which separates records.

The `/Integer/` matches records which contain Integer.